# Trouble populating listview from database

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this database that I need to populate a listview from and for some reason, it does get populated, but not with the actual values from the database, it just returns me references of my data in the database, I think it's returning to me the memory locations, I've posted my DBHelper.java, my ShirtsActivity.java where it'll be displayed and the needed xml file. So does anyone know why I'm not getting the actual values?

```js
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

public class Item {

    private String brand;
    //private String item;
    private String price;
    private String store;

    public Item() {

    }

    //public Item(String brand, String item, String price, String store) {
   //     super();
   //     this.brand = brand;
   //     this.item = item;
   //     this.price = price;
   //     this.store = store;
   // }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    //public void setItem(String item) {
    //    this.item = item;
    //}

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setStore(String store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public String getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    //public String getItem() {
    //    return item;
    //}

    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

}
```

```css
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Handler;

public class shirtsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shirts);

        final DatabaseHelper dbhelper;
        final ListView listView;
        final ListAdapter shirtsAdapter;

        dbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            dbhelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShirts);
        List<Item> shirtsList = dbhelper.getAllShirts();

        if(shirtsList != null){
            shirtsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                    shirtsList);
            listView.setAdapter(shirtsAdapter);
        }

    }

}
```

```html
package ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/ankitkaushal.app.healthysizing/databases/";
    public static String DB_NAME = "HealthySizing";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TB_USER = "Shirts";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
    private Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close(){
        if(myDB!=null){
            myDB.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public List<String> getAllUsers() {
        List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c;

        try {
            c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER , null);
            if(c == null) return null;

            String name;
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                name = c.getString(5);
                listUsers.add(name);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
        }


        db.close();

        return listUsers;
    }

    public List<Item> getAllShirts() {

        List<Item> shirtList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER; //query to get all the shirts
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        String price, brand, store;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Item item = new Item();
                price = cursor.getString(2);
                item.setPrice(price);
                item.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
                item.setBrand(cursor.getString(1));
                item.setStore(cursor.getString(3));
                shirtList.add(item);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return shirtList;

    }

    public Cursor getShirtsData() {
        String SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM" + TB_USER;
        return myDB.rawQuery(SQLQuery, null);
    }


    /***
     * Open database
     * @throws android.database.SQLException
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    /***
     * Copy database from source code assets to device
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        try {
            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;

            while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    /***
     * Check if the database doesn't exist on device, create new one
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {

        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // PRIVATE METHODS
    // ---------------------------------------------

    /***
     * Check if the database is exist on device or not
     * @return
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
        }
        if (tempDB != null)
            tempDB.close();
        return tempDB != null ? true : false;
    }


}
```

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#29A9D2"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/shirt"
    android:onClick="onClickSearch">

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchView3"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewShirts"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/shirtPrice"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/shirtBrand"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shirtPrice"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/shirtStore"
            android:layout_below="@+id/shirtBrand"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not extending `ArrayAdapter`, so the default action of `getView` is to call `toString()` on the items in the array.  Since you don't have a `toString()` method for `Item`, it's calling `Object.toString()` which displays that memory location you're seeing.

Eventually you'll have to write a custom adapter by extending `ArrayAdapter` and overriding `getView()`, but just so you can see it working a little bit, override `toString()` in your `Item` class and run it again.  You should see an improvement.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but the items are being displayed on one line, do you know how I can display the three items on different lines in the listview? I made the listview so that there are three textview objects on top of each other, but they aren't being displayed this way, when I run the app, so any idea on this?

Comment: It's the getView() method that determines how the item's data is placed in the item's view.  The getView() that comes with ArrayAdapter is very basic, so as I said in my answer, you have to create a subclass of ArrayAdapter<Item> and override getView() to put the item data where you want.

Comment: Yes, I did what you said, I used the getView() method and now it's displaying it correctly. But I've also now added a button to that listview for each object's information that I am displaying, and I would like to make it where when I click that button, it'll add that info to a shopping cart, which will be another activity so that all the items that I've clicked will display on that new page, any idea how I can do that?

Comment: There's a couple ways, one way is to call ListView.setOnItemClickListener() to tell you when the user clicks on a list item.  In your onItemClick() callback, you are passed the item position plus the listview from which you can get the adapter.  Call adapter.getItem(position) to get your Item.  Then put your item data in an Intent to send to your shopping cart activity.  Write some code and when you get stuck, ask a different question and post your code.  In the meantime, I'd be grateful if you marked my answer as correct, my co-worker has a 90K reputation and I'm trying to catch up. :)

Comment: Yes, I will work on that and I had one more question. If you look at my activity_shirts.xml, I also have a searchView and I need to make this work as well. So basically right now the listView gets populated from my database, but I need to make it where the user types in a brand that they are searching for say Nike and then display to them in the listView just the nike items, or just the items of whatever they type into the searchVie, so any idea how the searchView works and making it do what I need it to?

Comment: The SearchView uses list adapters just like the ListView, but it more specifically wants a CursorAdapter.  Here is a good tutorial on the Android developer site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html You will need to learn about Content Providers since they provide the search suggestions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html